# How can I effectively use Zangief in SF 4 Volt for iPad?

Tags: street-fighter-iv-volt

I'd like to get better at using Zangief in Street Fighter 4 Volt. I'm particularly interested in strategies to counter various other players, and effective high damage combos.

To be direct: countering teleporters, and ryu/chun-li vertical jump-kicks would be great.

I'd also appreciate links to any resources you use in writing your answers, for further research.

Comment: Comments purged, see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/why-was-my-question-looking-for-guides-closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't played Zangief or Street Fighter IV Volt in a long time, but this is something you should be aware of in online mode. I've read about people complaining about Zangief fighting teleporters such as M. Bison and Dhalsim, and [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/635554-street-fighter-iv-volt/61767536) thread has a good answer.

Basically, how you should play against teleporters online is by using green hand or body splash where the opponent is going to land. Also, another good tip mentioned there was to bait them to where you want them to go.

I did some additional research and found out that someone created a google document on all the possible combos and attack data for Zangief.

- The original thread can be viewed [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/635554-street-fighter-iv-volt/63009407)
- The google document can be viewed [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AvvU4sYRUOhBdHdtbXAwTXZUOVZCUzJCNHR1bHpiT0E&f=true&noheader=false&gid=3)

Comment: @bharal if this post solves your question you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Vs Teleporters
As they wake up, WALK TOWARDS SHORTER END of screen, as they start to teleport, GO TO LONG END OF SCREEN.. Get ready to SPD or Ultra them out of teleport.. You are essentially baiting them to into a teleport position for SPD..

Another popular tactic is BODY SPLASH BACKWARDS as they wake up..

During match, observe if they are single teleporters or two in a row teleporters.. Vs two-in-a-row teleports you may need to jump attack to force them to teleport, then 1 or 2 green hands to hit them when the solidify..

Vs Chun Li or NEUTRAL JUMP spammers
USE GIEF's df+P.. This attack has limited use, but is SPECIALLY designed for neutral jump spammers.. To neutral jump attacks df+P is more reliable than lariat.. Lariat NEEDS timing, and leaves you vulnerable if you miss.. df+P recovers faster and you don't get punished easy for missing..

Vs Bison neutral jump spam
When up close green-hand UNDER Bison and SPD his landing !! Works on Bison coz he floats in the air..
An alternative is to back dash and normal attack or SPD his landing !! Some ppl back dash, then EX green hand back !!

Vs FAST Characters
No throwing till you get em blocking some.. Use Gief's trusty P; it's universally useful (fast) and hits none blocking crouchers.. Use Gief's K which combos into d+K (which gives good window for SPD on counter hit).. Gief K also stops Cammy drill and Cammy air roll drill.. Gief K is a good low attack WHILE WALKING (no need crouch pause) !! Use jumping K instead of jumping fist against fast characters, quicker recovery and more active time; mix in splash too due to wide area.. No throwing until you get opponent hesitant with their speed, or you got em in hit/block stun with P or d+K or splash.. Mix short and long lariats, but mostly shor; also mix in EX green hand with normal green hand.. Save your Super meter for EX green hands !!